# Add value to array with key

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I've got a code in my wordpress:

```
        $wiadomosci = get_user_meta($user->ID,'wiadomosci', false);
        if($wiadomosci) {
            array_push($wiadomosci[$topic], $post->ID);
            update_user_meta($user->ID, 'wiadomosci', $wiadomosci);
        } else {
            $wiadomosci = array($topic => array($post->ID));
            add_user_meta($user->ID, 'wiadomosci', $wiadomosci);
        }
```

When a variable $wiadomosci doesnt exist I'm creating an array. $topic is the cateogory ID. So i'm getting this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [8] => Array
            (
                [0] => 139
            )

    )
```

)

8 is the category ID, and 139 post ID. Now when the variable $topic is 8 I want to add the post ID (for example 140) and get this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [8] => Array
            (
                [0] => 139
                [1] => 140
            )

    )

)
```

But I'm getting this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [8] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 139
                    )

            )

        [8] => 
    )

)
```

I'v tried replace

```
array_push($wiadomosci[$topic], $post->ID);
```

with:

```
$wiadomosci[$topic] = $post->ID
```

But it doesnt work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that [`wp_get_post_meta( ..., false )`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta) returns an array - the `false` means that the meta is multiple. Change the last argument to `true` and you should be set.

Answer (score -1):

if you do this in your else?

```
$wiadomosci = array($topic => $post->ID);
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok I've solved it. Here's the code:

```
        $wiadomosci = get_user_meta($user->ID,'wiadomosci', false);
        if($wiadomosci) {
            $tmp = $wiadomosci[0][$topic];
            $tmp[] = $post->ID;
            $wiadomosci[0][$topic] = $tmp;
            update_user_meta($user->ID, 'wiadomosci', $wiadomosci[0]);
        } else {
            $wiadomosci = array($topic => array($post->ID));
            add_user_meta($user->ID, 'wiadomosci', $wiadomosci);
        }
```